# linkedin profile call not giving exactly same response as we get it directly from browser

Tags: python, linkedin-api

```
url = https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,public-profile-url,three-current-positions)?oauth2_access_token=linkedin_access_token
import requests    
response = requests.get(url)
```

Here is excerpt from response content

```
<position>
 <id>581851303</id>
  <start-date>
     <year>2014</year>
     <month>9</month>
  </start-date>
  <is-current>true</is-current>
<company>
</company>
```

But the same url when opened in browser gives following output

```
<position>
  <id>581851303</id>
  <title>UPV grant</title>
  <summary>Historical building colour research Restoration research</summary>
  <start-date>
    <year>2013</year>
    <month>9</month>
  </start-date>
  <is-current>true</is-current>
  <company>
    <name>Departamento de Expresión Gráfica UPV</name>
  </company>
</position>
```

See title, summary and company name is missing in python response.

I tried applying user-agent header like

```
header = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.9; rv:32.0)
Gecko/20100101 Firefox/32.0',} in requests.get(url,headers=header)
```

But no improvement

Any idea how to get browser like content in python code?

Comment: Your url seems not right. Can you format it and make your post readable? Put code into code block.

Comment: Sorry mistake in copying the url here. I corrected the post.

Comment: Does anyone have idea on the issue I mentioned?